# how to collapse and expand a json in <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

`{
    "data": [ {
        "id": "ABC1", 
        "quantity": 10
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": "ABC2", 
        "quantity": -10
    }
    ]
}`

How can we collapse, if the Json structure is too long and expand it based on users wish in a page usin jquery!

Comment: You can use scroll bar where you displaying

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery JSONView plugin](https://github.com/yesmeck/jquery-jsonview).

Here is the [demo](http://yesmeck.github.io/jquery-jsonview/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the JQuery Plugins out there for "Pretty JSON tree viewers"

Below is the link to the first result on Google :
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Based-Pretty-Collapsible-JSON-Tree-Viewer.html